# C++ - [ ] operatorMap returning -1?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Does this mean that the item does not exist in the map? I was unable to find a documented answer showing that this was true.

Here is where I add to the map:

```
void Shader::addAttribute(const string attribute) 
{
    attributeList[attribute] = glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute.c_str());
}
```

I add to the map with:

```
shader.addAttribute("position");
```

Here is where I retrieve data from the map:

```
//An indexer that returns the location of the attribute
GLuint Shader::operator [](const string attribute) 
{
    return attributeList[attribute];
}
```

When I print the value in a debug log, I get "location is -1"

Comment: [From this:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) `Reference to the mapped value of the new element if no element with key key existed. Otherwise a reference to the mapped value of the existing element is returned.` I'm guessing the element's value is -1? Show us how you produce this result.

Comment: [Returns 0 here.](http://ideone.com/KueVM) The page also mentions the element being default-constructed, though.

Comment: @Aesthete good point. Updated

Comment: What does `glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute.c_str())` return?

Comment: [glGetAttribLocation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetAttribLocation.xml) -- *"If the named attribute variable is not an active attribute in the specified program object or if name starts with the reserved prefix 'gl_', a value of -1 is returned."*

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ahhh. So apparently, it cannot find it in the shader object. Wow. Thank you. That would have driven me crazy. Can you answer the question as well so I can confirm it so others can find the answer.

Comment: Just accept one of the answers that is there now.  They have both been edited with the information, or answer it yourself if you are not satisfied with theirs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of whatever key you're inserting into the map must be -1.

For:

```
std::map<int, int> map;
std::cout << (map [5]);
```

> If x (in your case, 5) does not match the key of any element in the container, the
>   function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference
>   to its mapped value.

What you've done here is you've assigned the value of `0` to a key of `5`

A map works by keys and values. It doesn't look like you quite understand how they operate. Normally you would do something like this:

```
std::map<int, int> map;
map[5] = 1; // map now contains one element, with a key of 5 and a value of 1
std::cout << (map [5]); // Prints 1
```

You've inserted a `-1` into you map in this call:

```
glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute.c_str())
```

Because, `glGetAttribLocation` returns -1 when, as **Benjamin** stated above, *"If the named attribute variable is not an active attribute in the specified program object or if name starts with the reserved prefix 'gl*', a value of -1 is returned."_. you should be doing something like the following:

```
int res = glGetAttribLocation(program, attribute.c_str())
if(res == -1)
{
  // Throw an exception, log an error.. Handle this error somehow.
}
else
{
  // Otherwise store the valid result.
  attributeList[attribute] = res; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `[]` operator always returns something because it *creates* values that do not exist for the given key (otherwise returning the existing mapping for the key).  Newly-created values will use the default constructor for the data type, whatever that is; it depends on your template arguments.  Apparently your chosen data type uses -1 as its default value.

Edit: Based on updated question, `glGetAttribLocation()` must be returning -1 and that value ends up in the map.

Comment: Or, more likely I think, the element was already in there, and it was assigned a value of -1.

Comment: How can a type have -1 as its default value? The default value of type T must be of type T, right? -1 has type int, so it could only be the default value of type int. However the default value of int is 0, not -1.

Comment: If type `T` is primitive (e.g. `int`) then yes, it must already have existed with a value of -1.  On the other hand if `T` is a class with a constructor, it could be a type that defaults to -1 when it's created (and for that matter, a type that has an operator to cast itself back to a number).  I didn't see any details to suggest what types are in this particular map.

Comment: Based on the updated question I'd say that `glGetAttribLocation()` is producing the -1 value and you're then putting that in the map.